# Sequence identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let be $p$ a positive integer;
$a_k$ and $b_k$ sequences of integers;
$c_k$ a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers.

Suppose that

$$ p=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{a_k}{c_k}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{b_k}{c_k}.$$

Is it sure that

$a_k=b_k$ for every $k\ge N$ for some $N$?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
a_k=\{1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots\}\\
b_k=\{0,2,0,0,0,0,\ldots\}\\
c_k=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots\}
$$

Comment: and if $a_k$ and $b_k$ are not $0$ definitely?

Comment: or is it true that $a_k=b_k$ for every $k \ge N$ for some $N$ ?

Comment: I am pretty sure there are counterexamples for both statements. If you are not satisfied with my counterexample, please provide more context so we can figure out what you would like to achieve, ultimately.