# $A = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{a_i}$ and $1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fractions, egyptian-fractions

I have the following problem :

For a given positive real $A>1$

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{a_i}$$

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_i}$$

$$a_{n+1}>a_{n}$$

where $a_i$ is a strictly increasing sequence of strict positive integers.

How to find $a_i$ for a given closed form $A$, in particular in some kind of closed form ?

I was thinking about continued fractions , odd greedy expansions, engel expansions, fractal fractions and such things.

Is the solution even unique ??

See also :

[Sequence identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212142/sequence-identity)

---

I want to add that there exists a lower bound for $A$ IF $a_1 = 2$ that is larger than $1$ and a bound for the rate of $a_i$.
This is explained by

$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{b_i}$$

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b_i}$$

$$b_{n+1}>b_{n}$$

Where $b_i$ equals to Sylvester's sequence $2,3,7,43,1807,...$,
the sum of its (Sylvester's sequence) forms a series of unit fractions that converges to 1 more rapidly than any other series of unit fractions.

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence

Hence our $A > B$ IF $a_1 = 2$.

I have no closed form for $B$, if you know one let me know.
Digits of $B$ are nice too.

Analogue bounds exists for other values of $a_1$.

---

It seems related to integral transforms but in a discrete form.

Any ideas how to find $a_i$ for a given $A$ ?

In particular

$A = U + V \pi + W e$

Where $U,V,W$ are rationals and $\pi$ and $e$ are the famous constants

is of special interest to me.